# Extracting time with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get just the time out of this line

```
10.11.17.31 - ldjfu [20/Aug/2018:00:00:40 -0600] GET /aghdj/shflf/heartbeat HTTP/1.0 200 650 - F5 Heartbeat EExL34L-CFYSLHwerKajtqP2Z8bf 0.006
```

Doing this:

```
/^.*\[(.*)\].*/
```

gives me

```
20/Aug/2018:07:35:52 -0600
```

but I only want

```
07:35
```

I have tried to manipulate my regex pattern but no better eliminating the items I don't need.

Comment: You can also do it in two steps before trying to super optimize it. You already extracted something, the date with all items from which you want only some. So apply a second regex on this new string. Or do a split on `:` and keep items at position 1 and 2.

Comment: That regex pattern with the data you show captures `20/Aug/2018:00:00:40 -0600`. How do you get `07:35` from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are to believe your regex pattern match results rather than the input data you show, then

```
my ($time) = /:(\d\d:\d\d)/
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine